# Como crear un input select con woocommerce_form_field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hola comunidad espero se encuentren bien. Estaría agradecido de su ayuda, estoy intentando crear un input select en Woocommerce con la funcion woocommerce_form_field(), quería saber si es posible que cada option tenga un data-value, pero con el codigo actual no eh podido lograrlo. Adjunto el

```
codigo actual woocommerce_form_field( 'mi_select', array(
    'type'     => 'select',
    'label'    => 'Mi Select',
    'options'  => array(
        'opcion1' => 'Opción 1',
        'opcion2' => 'Opción 2',
        'opcion3' => 'Opción 3',
    ),
    'class'    => array( 'mi-clase' ),
    'custom_attributes' => array(
        'data-value' => 'mi-atributo',
    ),
), 'valor_actual' );
```

Comment: por lo general un `data-value` va en el select que recibe el value, para capturar el value/texto de cada option podes usar `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value` / `select.options[select.selectedIndex].text` el source de la function no parece soportar attributos extra en los options https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/55faf9dcdab1b123dfc74dab5fad4192f578c6a7/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2969